# Why are some documents inside document sets shown when filtering for document set meta data?

Tags: 2010, content-type, managed-metadata, document-set

I have a very strange issue: Two files (excel files) - each belonging to a different document set - are shown within the top level view when using a specific Key Filter setting which should only be relevant to the document sets in my library.

**Document Library Settings (Content Types)**

Simplified, I have a document library with the following two content types

- *Basic Document Set*

  - Content Type: Derived from "Document Set"
  - Column "Relevance Status"

    - Type: Managed Metadata (points to a very small and flat taxonomy: {Active, Historical})
- *Basic Document*

  - Content Type: Derived from "Document"

**Document Library Content**

Based on the above content types, my document library looks as following:

```
DocumentationA
DocumentationA/FileA.xlsx
DocumentationB
DocumentationB/FileB.xlsx
```

- *DocumentationA* and *DocumentationB* are both document sets of type "Basic Document Set"
- *FileA.xlsx* and *FileB.xlsx* are both documents of type "Basic Document"
- *DocumentationA* has a "Relevance Status" set to "Historical"
- *DocumentationB* has a "Relevance Status" set to "Active"

**Metadata Navigation Settings**

Since I want to hide/show certain document sets using the "Relevance Status" , I have configured this field as "Key Filter Field" with an automatic index creation.

**Issue: Filtering shows unrelated files**

When I filter the documents using the "Relevance Status" "Historical", only the document set *DocumentationA* appears: This is fine and what I expect **BUT** when I filter the documents using the "Relevance Status" "Active", the document set *DocumentationB* **AS WELL AS** both excel files *FileA.xlsx* and *FileB.xlsx* appear. **Why?**

I cannot see any connection between these files and document sets. Clearly the documents don't have this column I am filtering. 
BTW: The view settings in *Folder* are set to *Show items inside folders*.

Comment: I guess that you have double checked that the Relevance Status for FileA.xlsx has not been changed to Active? Even if the status is Historical on the document set, the value for the documents in the Doc set can be changed to something else.

Comment: Well, that's the strange thing: The content type of my documents does not even have this column. That's what makes me worried...

Answer (score 0):

The IT department was able to solve my issue with some kind of a workaround:

**Removing a default value from the site column avoids triggering this issue.**

I was told that the documents inherit the default value of the document set as hidden properties even if they don't have the property defined.